# Checking out branch and rebasing/merging temporarily to see impact?

Tags: git, github

Oftentimes, in our workflow we have a branch which tracks a remote pending pull request and I want to see preemptively what that PR will do to my PR before it's merged into master. For example, let's say there's a PR branch `bar` that hasn't been merged into `master` but I want to see how my PR branch `foo` which is being developed concurrently will be impacted by this change.

So I was thinking I could rebase `foo` onto `bar` (or merge) and then use `reflog` to reset `foo` back to its original spot, effectively undoing the rebase. However, I thought there may be a more efficient/elegant way to do this. Is there any similar functionality that would stop the branch pointer from being moved but allow us to see (in maybe a detached HEAD state) what impact one branch has on the other?

Comment: Simply create and check out a throwaway branch `foo2` that points to the same commit as `foo` does (`git checkout -b foo2 foo`); do whatever you want with `foo2`, then remove it. This approach is simpler and safer than manipulating `foo` (and its reflog) directly.

Comment: @jubobs wow that's really smart actually! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply...

1. Create and check out a throwaway branch, named `foo2`, say, that points to the same commit as `foo` does:

   ```
   git checkout -b foo2 foo
   ```
2. Do whatever you want with branch `foo2` (rebase it, etc.).
3. When you're done, remove `foo2`:

   ```
   git branch -d foo2
   ```

This approach is simpler and safer than manipulating `foo` (and its reflog) directly.